# How to inspect any element in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to perform the mouse hover, where 2 elements have same class name. I want to click on second element but its clicking on first element. How to locate the second one if there is only `class` and `href` attributes given.

I've tried to create my own xpath using `classname` and `href` but its not working.

Comment: Can you please add you code ?

Comment: please read about Array, list, indexing and whatever language you are using to code webriver.

Comment: After inspecting the elements with firebug I am getting the below code: 1)<a class="desktop-main" data-reactid="137" style="border-bottom-color:#fb56c1;" data-type="navElements" data-color="#fb56c1" data-group="women" data-index="1" href="/shop/women">Women</a>

Comment: second code is 2)<a class="desktop-main" data-reactid="137" style="border-bottom-color:#fb56c1;" data-type="navElements" data-color="#fb56c1" data-group="women" data-index="1" href="/shop/women">Women</a>... For this I am using a code 1)driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='desktop-main' and @href='/shop/women']/div"));                                                                                                   2)driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='desktop-main' and @text()='Women']/div"));  I need to click on second element

Comment: If I am using only className then its clicking on the first element but I want to click the second element. What can be the code in this case?

Comment: I tried this option also:  By.xpath("(//a[@class='desktop-main'])[2]")

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the className selector and then using index to get the "2nd" element with that class name.

For this element:

```
<a class="desktop-main" data-reactid="137" style="border-bottom-color:#fb56c1;" data-type="navElements" data-color="#fb56c1" data-group="women" data-index="1" href="/shop/women">Women</a>
```

Try this:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("desktop-main");
elements.get(1).click();
```

Comment: The above code is working fine but still my problem is not solved. The task is to perform the mouse hover. I need to hover the mouse on the second element and then I need to click on sub menus..If I am executing the above command it will only click on main menu but not on sub menu.

Comment: I am using the below given website to do the task: "https://www.myntra.com/" and for this I want to do the mouse hover on Women Tab then want to click on Any submenu. For this I am using the below code:                                                              java.util.List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("desktop-main"));
  elements.get(1).findElement(By.linkText("Tops, T-Shirts & Shirts")).click();